# adding all digits up to 10 in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

i thought i had an idea how to do it using only add,sub,mult,addi,and,or,andi,ori,lw,sw,beq,bne,slt,slti,mflo.

i have to make sure every detail is in there, the stack pointer is clear etc.

any help solving this please?  not for homework, just for studying for a test.  i tried working it out and got it wrong, and just want to see a correct solution so i can see what i did wrong.  i would ask my professor but he doesn't have office hours today and i need to figure this out tonight since i'm busy for the rest of the week

Comment: Please, place what you have up here so we know where to start.  BTW, this does sound exactly like homework.

Comment: aware, but its not.  swear on my mother's life.  its for a "cheat sheet" we get to use on our test tomorrow.  and i can put up what i have exactly when i get back to my room, its on my computer there

Comment: "cheat sheets" for a test the next day fall into the category "homework" in my book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real reason to do anything with the stack pointer unless we want to keep something on the stack. However in such a simple program, it's easier to work exclusively with registers. (using only add,sub,mult,addi,and,or,andi,ori,lw,sw,beq,bne,slt,slti,mflo.)

```
    .text
    .global main
main:
    addi    $t0, $zero, 10          # (counter) we will start with 10 and go down to zero
    add     $t1, $zero, $zero       # (sum) our sum, 0
count:
    add     $t1, $t1, $t0           # sum += counter
    addi    $t0, $t0, -1            # counter -= 1
    bne     $t0, $zero, count       # if (counter) goto count
    add     $v0, $zero, $t1         # return value, our sum
    #jr     $ra                     # return (jr not allowed?)
```

If you really wanted to utilize the stack to store the local variables (count and sum), you could do something like this. However, as you can see, it's a quite extensive and unnecessary.

```
    .text
    .global main
main:
    addi    $sp, $sp, -12       # Make room on the stack ($ra, sum, counter)
    sw      $ra, 0($sp)         # save the return address (not really needed)
    sw      $zero, 4($sp)       # sum variable, set to 0
    addi    $t0, $zero, 10
    sw      $t0, 8($sp)         # counter variable, set to 10
count:
    lw      $t0, 4($sp)         # load sum
    lw      $t1, 8($sp)         # load counter
    add     $t0, $t0, $t1       # sum += counter
    addi    $t1, $t1, -1        # counter -= 1
    sw      $t0, 4($sp)         # save the sum value
    sw      $t1, 8($sp)         # save the counter
    bne     $t1, $zero, count   # if (counter) goto count

    lw      $v0, 4($sp)         # return value, the sum
    lw      $ra, 0($sp)         # restore caller's address
    addi    $sp, $sp, 12        # pop the stack
    #jr     $ra                 # return to caller (jr not allowed?)
```